# Google's ImmutableList

Tags: java, immutability

I am new to immutablelist and try to understand it better. As far as I understand once you have the immutable list in object it cannot be modified. but I am slightly confused as it used in the pojo.

Can I have immutableList as an attribute of pojo and define getter / setter of it ?
If I do that, what will be implication of doing it.

Comment: See [Immutable object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) to understand what the benefits are of making things immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it in POJOs, yes. However, with collections and POJOs in general you should be careful.

Here is what you should do if your immutable list is an instance field:

```
// list is immutable
public List<X> getList() { return list; }
public void setList(final List<X> list) { this.list = ImmutableList.copyOf(list); }
```

All too often, in beans code, using a non immutable collection, you will see that:

```
// list is mutable -- DON'T DO THAT
public List<X> getList() { return list; }
public void setList(final List<X> list) { this.list = list; }
```

But this is very, very unsafe:

- you return a reference to the list; this reference can be modified (`ImmutableList` does not have this problem!);
- you set a new reference to the list, which can *also* be modified.

What *should* be done is:

```
// list is mutable
public List<X> getList() { return Collections.unmodifiableList(list); }
public void setList(final List<X> list) { this.list = new ArrayList<>(list); }
```

Comment: Why? It's immutable. Why copy it?

Comment: @bmargulies For two reasons: 1. you may well have a non immutable list as an argument; 2. this static factory method is smart enough _not_ to copy the list if it is detected that it is an instance of `ImmutableList`.

Comment: Oh, oh, I didn't notice that you didn't demand an immutable input. oops.

Comment: Thanks fge, out of 1 code snapshot and 3rd snapshot what is preferred ?

Comment: Well, if you use `ImmutableList`, go for 1; however, remind that the returned collection will be immutable: if you need the caller to be able to modify it, you'll have to change the code.